# Openpyxl - How to copy data range from an excel worksheet to another

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to copy a range of data based on row coordinates from a sheet to another.

I have a list with row coordinates 
`tbrow = [1, 34, 52, 75, 101]`

What I would like to do is to copy the row range from:

1 to 34 from sheet 0 to sheet 1,

34 to 52 from sheet 0 to sheet 2,

52 to 75 from sheet 0 to sheet 3,

75 to 101 from sheet 0 to sheet 4.

What I tried so far is the following:

-Get the main sheet 0

`sheet0 = wb["Sheet"]`

Then I stored the sheets in a variable, ignoring the first sheet

`sheets = wb.worksheets[1:]`

In the end, I tried to copy the given values.

`for i in range(tbrow[i],tbrow[i]+1)
    for j in range(1,sheet0.max_column+1):
        for k in sheets:
            k.cell(row=i, column=j).value = sheet0.cell(row=i, column=j).value`

Problem is that I get only the first row copied to the rest of the sheets and not the whole range. (1-34;34-52 and so on)
What am I missing?

Can anyone help me on organizing a logic in here? Or provide a solution?

Thank you!

> **UPDATE**

Another approach was to slice the list.

`a,b = tbrow[:2] 
for i in range(a,b): 
    for j in range(1,sheet1.max_column+1): 
        for k in sheets: k.cell(row=i, column=j).value = sheet1.cell(row=i, column=j).value`

But that takes only the first two row coordinates from the list and I would like to go to the next item in the list:

-From first to second

-From second to third

-From third to fourth

...and so on –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I notice with your code is the value of `i` inside the range method. The `i` inside the range method is not the same as the `i` being used in the for loop. I am assuming you must have a global definition of `i=0` which is then not updated, hence why only the first rows are copied to the next sheet.

```
for i in range(tbrow[i],tbrow[i]+1):#------here
    for j in range(1,sheet0.max_column+1):
        for k in sheets:
            k.cell(row=i, column=j).value = sheet0.cell(row=i, column=j).value
```

Consider using a function where u can the pass the values of the rows

```
def addRowsToSheet(lb,ub):
    for i in range(lb,ub):#------here
        for j in range(1,sheet0.max_column+1):
              #consider using switch case, instad of the loop
              switch (ub):
                  case 34:
                    sheets[0].cell(row=i, column=j).value = sheet0.cell(row=i, column=j).value;
                    sheets[1].cell(row=i, column=j).value = sheet0.cell(row=i, column=j).value;
                  case 52:
                    sheets[2].cell(row=i, column=j).value = sheet0.cell(row=i, column=j).value;

              #Do the same logic below

#calls
for i in range(0,len(tbrow)-1):
     addRowsToSheet(tbrow[i],tbrow[i+1])
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the next item in the list (like you used: case (34,52..) without mentioning them?
Considering that I want to increment automatically through the list without looking at the values and naming them.


Same goes for the sheet. 
Copy from first sheet to next and then copy from first to next+1 and so on.

Comment: you would somewhere need to have a conditinal to determine the sheets and the rows to be applied. one of the changes you can do for this is in the calling loop pass the `i` as a another parameter. In the function then add the loop`for k in range(0,len(new_param)-1):` for the values of k use sheets[k] to update the sheet. This time instewd of switch just use if statements, e.g. if k < 2 : add it to sheets 0, 2